# What is the difference between Hardware reserve Standby and Free memory and how is it possible that my PC works slower on all available 13K RAM

Tags: memory, windows-8.1, performance

My PC is slower now with Standby memory 13K+ than when I used 8K Hardware reserved (it was then much faster)

Why is this?

What is the difference between Hardware reserve Standby and Free memory?

I am using Windows 8.1 64bit 700 @ 2.80 GHz 2.82 GHz and 16 Giga RAM with a Geforce GT 640 graphic card

Comment: If understood you correctly, you have a problem with your RAM, If you just upgraded your rams, then you have to make sure that the RAMs are compatible with your Mobo, if is it compatible, then you can try to plug them off, and re-insert them again, and that could fix the problem. Remember to do that while your computer is unplugged from the power source, and if possible, unplug the power connectors from the motherboard before you put your hands on anything, this will make sure to do it correctly.

Comment: How do i see if the ram is compatible with me PC? or (Mobo what ever it is)

Comment: You can check your motherboard manual, and see what type of RAM supported. If you can tell me what motherboard you have, I can tell you which RAM it supports and what is the best choice for it to work perfectly. Also, tell me which kind of rams you have or if you ordered online, you can just give me its page.

Comment: I have an ASUS P7P55D motherboard and 2 sticks on 8 Giga RAM S.Skill company (www.gskill.com)

Comment: http://www.gskill.com/en/product/f3-1333c9d-16gao

Comment: post some pictures of RAMMap when you have issues: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is your ASUS P7P55D Motherboard RAM Specifications:

```
4 x DIMM, Max. 16 GB, DDR3 2200(O.C.)*/1600/1333/1066 Non-ECC,Un-buffered Memory
Dual Channel memory architecture
Supports Intel® Extreme Memory Profile (XMP)
```

Your motherboard has a maximum of 16GB of RAM divided into 4 slots, each slot can handle a 4GB of RAM at max.

In Other word, the following specifications is what you need:

- Memory Type : DDR3
- Clock Speed : 2200(Overclock) OR 1600 OR 1333 OR 1066
- Registered/Unbuffered: Unbuffered
- Error Checking: Non-ECC

What you have done is that you've inserted 2x 8GB RAMs, into 2 slots which exceeded the max RAM capacity for each slot, and that's your problem. So, you have to change them to a 4x 4GB RAM if you want a 16GB. the one you have are compatible, but it should be 4x 4GB, rather than 2x 8GB !

Once you do that, your system should recognize the full 16GB of RAM and everything is going to work just fine.

Comment: Is it possible for me to add another 2 of 8 giga?

Comment: So the total will be 32,will it work? or just X4 of 4 giga?

Comment: @Alex No it's impossible to do that, as I said, your motherboard supports only 16GB, so you need a 4 sticks of 4GB RAM to work correctly.

Comment: Allright,last question

Comment: What if i unplug one stick? is it will be better?cause i remmember it was better performance befor i started to try access full 16 giga,befor that it was 16 and 8 usable (Hardwere reserved)

Comment: you have to put only what the motherboard support, So you give it what it needs exactly, it'll gives you the best it could do, if you give it more than it needs, it'll gives you some problems.